# SVG <LinearGradient> appears black on PDF export (PhantomJS)

Tags: pdf, svg, phantomjs, linear-gradients

In our application we generate lots of various PDFs containing SVGs, and all of them render without any issues. The only exception is this linear gradient. Is there anything wrong about this SVG?

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="476" height="227">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#008000">
            </stop>
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff0000">
            </stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff">
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="17.393672215737514" y="205.945" width="122.87932223519165" height="10.055" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

**Update**

As confirmed by **K J** the SVG is fully valid. So that must be some phantomJS rendering problem. Although I doubt that during all those years that PhantomJS is being actively used no one else faced same problem (generating PDFs containing SVGs with linear gradients seems a pretty common use case to me). PhantomJS-2.1.1 uses QtWebKit 538.1, but I wasn't able to find anyone reporting any related issues neither for phantomjs nor for qtwebkit.

Also I had a suspicion that it might be somehow related to `<base>` tag. I've met multiple times information about `<base>` tag influencing the url referencing `<linearGradient>` ID. But after doing some testing I came to conclusion that this is not the case, because when url is bad, my gradient element is completely blank.

I'm including this image to show my webpage against PDF output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that SVG gradient when converted in any suitable fashion

[image]

Thus the problem must lie in the application tolerance of that input.
There are no reported open issues related to gradient, https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/search?q=gradient&type=issues, so perhaps you need to open a fresh one with your coding method.

Comment: @K J thanks for the input! I basically came to same conclusion. There is no much point in opening an issue for PhantomJS, as it is not being maintained for many years. Also I have updated my question with a bit more info.